# How do I auto-fill in this textbox at the US govt website via the URL?

Tags: html, url, textbox

I'm trying to embed a value into the textbox at the [USCIS government website](https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do) to check my application status number.  Suppose it's `LIN1234`.  After inspecting the element of the webpage I see that the HTML wrapper for the textbox is:

```
<input id="receipt_number" name="appReceiptNum" class="form-control textbox initial-focus" maxlength="13" type="text">
```

I tried opening up this URL with a suffix added on, but to no avail:

```
https://egov.uscis.gov/casestatus/landing.do?receipt_num=LIN1234
```

Is there a way to to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before that, you must understand what means adding `?receipt_num=LIN1234` to the url.

When sending a request (By default and in this context) from your browser, it'll be a `GET` request ([see here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)) where you send as a get argument your receipt number, setting its key to receipt_num.

What is done to this data on the server side, however, is up to itself.
Just understand that unless the server is made to auto-fill the field with that value in case it receives it, it won't do anything except sending some more data.

I think you want to load this page in your browser with auto-filled field.
In that case you should look into extensions for your browser that would do that automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't be able to embed a value into the textbox... Just because you are sending values by GET (which is what the landing.do?receipt_num=LIN1234 syntax is doing) doesn't mean that they have something set up to process it, so the GET variable will probably not do anything.

You *might* be able to see how their URLs work ordinarily, what the page URL that you are aiming to land on looks like, and either decode something from that or set a bookmark there. That said, if they are submitting that data via POST (which they probably are, for security reasons), that probably won't work.

I would suggest looking at reputable form-filling plugins for your web browser, if that's an option. That might allow you to work around that.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer is at its core identical to Artemis's, but I gave the check to him because he answered a minute earlier.  Much appreciated regardless.